# How do you change a rosservice parameter in python?

Tags: navigation, rospy, rosservice, robot-localization, rosservices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the `robot_localization` package, specifically the `ekf_localization` and `navsat_transform nodes`. I want to re-set the `datum` parameter in `navsat_transform`, I know that I can achieve this using:

```
rosservice call /datum <tab>
```

But I want to also be able to re-set it from a python script. The datum has a service to re-set it (the service message is [here](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/robot_localization/html/srv/SetDatum.html)). I've tried working it out by working through the ROS python service tutorials, and the closest I've got to success is this:

```
rospy.wait_for_service('datum')
try:
    geo_pose = rospy.ServiceProxy('datum', GeoPose)
    geo_pose = preset_pose
except rospy.ServiceException, e:
    print "Service call failed: %s"%e
```

Which is definitely wrong because it produces this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/matt/autosys_repo1/custom_jackal_ws/src/waypoint_manager/src/waypoint_manager.py", line 239, in     <module>
    node.run()
   File "/home/matt/autosys_repo1/custom_jackal_ws/src/waypoint_manager/src/waypoint_manager.py", line 230, in run
    self.execute_user_command()
   File "/home/matt/autosys_repo1/custom_jackal_ws/src/waypoint_manager/src/waypoint_manager.py", line 201, in execute_user_command
    self.set_frame_origin()  
   File "/home/matt/autosys_repo1/custom_jackal_ws/src/waypoint_manager/src/waypoint_manager.py", line 146, in set_frame_origin
    geo_pose = rospy.ServiceProxy('datum', GeoPose)
   File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 404, in __init__
    super(ServiceProxy, self).__init__(name, service_class)
   File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/service.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.request_class = service_class._request_class
AttributeError: type object 'GeoPose' has no attribute '_request_class'
```

And I'm not sure If the message is telling me that I've got the syntax/code wrong or if I can't actually change the `datum` parameter via `rospy`. For reference, here are my system details:

**Robot:** Clearpath Jackal UGV

**OS:** Ubuntu 14.04 on laptop, Ubuntu server on robot

**ROS distro:** Indigo Igloo

**robot_localization version:** 2.2.2 binaries

Thank you in advance for any advice or help!

### UPDATE 1

In response to ahendrix's answer:

Thanks for the help again ahendrix! When I try the code you posted as-is I get this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/matt/autosys_repo1/custom_jackal_ws/src/waypoint_manager/src/waypoint_manager.py", line 397, in <module>
     node.run()
   File "/home/matt/autosys_repo1/custom_jackal_ws/src/waypoint_manager/src/waypoint_manager.py", line 388, in run
     self.execute_user_command()
   File "/home/matt/autosys_repo1/custom_jackal_ws/src/waypoint_manager/src/waypoint_manager.py", line 306, in execute_user_command
     self.reset_map_frame()
   File "/home/matt/autosys_repo1/custom_jackal_ws/src/waypoint_manager/src/waypoint_manager.py", line 255, in reset_map_frame
     geo_pose = rospy.ServiceProxy('datum', SetDatum)
 NameError: global name 'SetDatum' is not defined
```

Now obviously this is because nothing has defined 'SetDatum' yet, and I assume this has to be defined by SetDatum.srv, but when I try to import it I just get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matt/autosys_repo1/custom_jackal_ws/src/waypoint_manager/src/waypoint_manager.py", line 22, in <module>
    from SetDatum.srv import *
ImportError: No module named SetDatum.srv
```

Despite that the file *does* exist in the ROS files. I've also found a file in the `robot_localization` services folder labelled `_SetDatum.py`, in that is a whole bunch of code that looks like it's meant to be used to set the datum, but I don't know how to use it (in general I've found the services tutorials to be very short on explanation)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239194/how-do-you-change-a-rosservice-parameter-in-python?/) by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2327 on 2016-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error message is telling you that GeoPose isn't a serivce type.

If you want to call a service with the `SetDatum` type, you should create your service proxy with the `SetDatum` type:

```
rospy.wait_for_service('datum')
try:
    geo_pose = rospy.ServiceProxy('datum', SetDatum)
    response = geo_pose(preset_pose) # preset_pose should be a GeoPose object
except rospy.ServiceException, e:
    print "Service call failed: %s"%e
```

**EDIT**

The proper import for `SetDatum` should be:

```
from robot_localization.srv import SetDatum
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2016-07-12**:
Yeap, that did the trick, thanks again ahendrix!